# What is expected for the EnvelopeAttachment parameters of "Type" and "Label"?

Tags: docusignapi

What is expected for the label and type?  I want to attach some documents to envelopes at envelope creation time and I want anyone viewing the envelope to be able to see them, so I think this is the right place for it (correct me if that is wrong).  But, no matter what, I still need to know what is expected for the properties of the Attachment object.

Comment: Which DocuSign API are you using, SOAP or REST?

Comment: The SOAP API.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to what's known as **Signer Attachments** in DocuSign.  Signer attachments are envelope tabs that allow recipients to add extra attachments to the envelope when it is their turn in the routing order.  While you add signer attachment tabs for your recipients when you are creating the envelope (just like how you add signature tabs or date tabs etc) the actual file attachment doesn't happen until *after* the envelope has been sent, when it's that recipients turn.

If you want to add another file to the envelope that is in the draft state and you want all recipients to be able to see it, then you would just add another document to the envelope but don't configure any tabs on that document.  Then the recipients would only be able to read that document and not perform any actions on it.

Since it looks like you are using the SOAP API, there is actually a code walkthrough that was written a little while ago which shows how to make use of the EnvelopeAttachment object, and it also shows how to set the TabLabel and the Type.  Please see here:

http://www.docusign.com/content/e-signature-code-walkthrough-signer-attachments

Comment: I don't want recipients to add documents.  I want to attach supporting documents.  For example, let's say I have a generic form for financials and the doc they are signing is the rollup of the numbers.  I want to be able to attach images and other types of files, when I create the envelope, that all recipients will be able to see, that contain things like invoices or check images, etc...  Thanks.

Comment: So then the second paragraph of my answer should suit your needs.  When you are adding documents to your envelope you are free to add images, docs, or other files and you can control the order that they show up in the envelope.  As mentioned, you simply don't add any DocuSign tabs to those docs and everyone will be able to read them but they won't have to sign or date them, etc.

Comment: So the PDFBytes property will just be set to the file contents (even if it is not a PDF) and then I supply the file extension if it is not actually a PDF?

Comment: That's correct.  Just add another file the same way you added your envelope document(s) but give whatever file extension it is if it's not a PDF.  I forgot you're using SOAP so you'll have to do this when creating the envelope.  If you were using REST (which by the way you can both SOAP and REST calls on the same envelope) then you would be able to add more docs to a draft envelope through [this call](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Add%20Documents%20to%20a%20Draft%20Envelope.htm)