# receiving INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT when updating envelope status

Tags: docusignapi

I have an envelope, that if created with status=sent works fine (I can call the signing
interface and it gets emailed to the recipients defined in the envelope).  The exact same envelope XML, with status=created, no other difference, will fail when I attempt to change the status with:

```
public string SendEnvelope(string envelopeID)
{
    string url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeID;
    string requestBody =
    "<envelope>" +
    "<status>sent</status>" +
    "</envelope>";
    HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "PUT", requestBody, email, password);
    string response = getResponseBody(request); <---ERROR OCCURS HERE
    return response;
}
```

I receive:
INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENTThe email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows.

Is it not possible to set the envelope status to "sent" at any time after envelope creation ?

Comment: If you create an envelope with status=created, and provide an invalid email address, the envelope does get created successfully - it is considered in 'draft' mode. The error you are seeing indicates that the recipients email address does not conform to the email address format of a@b.c   If you try to actually send an envelope with the invalid email@ still there, you should see the INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT error.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but that's not the situation.  All email addresses are valid: if I create the envelope as "sent" instead of "created" (no other changes to XML), it works fine.  It is only getting an error when trying to update the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, if you have a template role assigned of "carbon copy", and you don't provide any email addresses for that role, then it produces the invalid email address error.

Comment: FYI - even though I'm not generating the markup for the CC template role in the envelope if there are no CCs, it still produces the error.  At this point, it looks like you HAVE to include the templaterole tag for all templateroles in your template AND fill them with at least one email address.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was not setting ccRoles in template definition at the time of creating the draft template. Strange thing is it works if you create an envelope in 'sent' status, but not when you try to create it in 'created' status and later try to update the status to 'sent'

I was doing

```
env.templateRoles = [signerRoles];
```

but the fix was

```
env.templateRoles = [...templateRoles, ...ccRoles];
```